# Apple Watch pausing while being worn and paired with Heart Sensor

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

I want to force my Apple Watch to track activities while using a paired heart sensor, but I don't want to wear the watch during certain activities i.e. when doing martial arts, etc.

However, once I take it off my wrist for such activities, the watch automatically pauses the activity. I tried to disable Auto Pause on the settings menu but to no avail. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you’ll have luck modifying watchOS so perhaps a different band to get the watch off a wrist but still in proximity of your skin would help:

- https://www.twelvesouth.com/product/actionsleeve